# disable cache on firestore in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How to disable get/stream data from cache on firestore?

I saw this article. this feature is by default enable [PersistenceEnabled](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/enable-offline)

Is it a clear cache in this way?

```
void main() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.clearPersistence();
```

OR

Is it need to add to every query?

```
  Future<List<BookModel>> _getBooks() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.clearPersistence();
    return _db.collection('books')...  
    }
```

OR

How to disable cache on firestore all time?

Is it correct?

```
void main() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings = 
Settings(
persistenceEnabled: false,
cacheSizeBytes: ?,//is it need add this fields too?
host: ?,
sslEnabled: ?
```

);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `clearPersistence` clears the local cache, but doesn't disable it. So any database calls after that will start populating the local cache again.

To disable the client from using the cache, you'll need to set `persistenceEnabled` to false when the app starts.

Comment: is it okay to clear cache after app start?(any moment)

Comment: and also if disable is there any chance to slow? example: (text with image data) - without disable, 5 seconds to data fetch, and after disable more than 5 seconds or same time?

Comment: is data usage(db calls) increase after disable?

Comment: 1) "You must set these before invoking any other methods on this FirebaseFirestore instance." https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FirebaseFirestore/settings.html 2) yes, the local database will perform very different from the server, how precisely you'll have to measure 3) if you have no local data, all data has to come from the server, so that'll be charged.

Comment: one more question. Is it automatically cache clean when a new app version? if no, is there any issue to clean cache when new version of app?