# Flutter Firestore not giving updated data when I add a field to a document from the console

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream, riverpod

I'm facing an odd bug in Flutter Firestore 2.5.3 where if I add a new field (`customer_type`) to a document in the Firebase Console, the app fails to retrieve the newly added field and throws an exception:

`CastError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)`

But it isn't null. I added the new field with the value from the Firebase Console. It's there in the document. Turns out Firebase is getting the old document data **without** the newly added field.

I'm using a `StreamProvider` from Riverpod. Here's the code:

```
static Stream<Customer?> _watchCustomer(final ProviderRefBase ref) async* {
  final auth = await ref.watch(authProvider.last);
  if (auth == null) {
    yield null;
  } else {
    final customerRef = _db.collection('customers').toCustomerRef(auth.uid);
    await for (var customer in customerRef.snapshots().map((doc) => doc.data())) yield customer;
  }
}
```

What could be going wrong?

**EDIT:**

**All the names, collection & field are correct and so is their type. If I re-install the app or fully clear app storage, the same exact code will work just fine. However, if I just clear the cache it doesn't work. It impedes my workflow when debugging and I'd like to know why it's happening. For additional reference, here is my "Customer" model:**

```
Customer.fromMap(final String documentID, final Map<String, dynamic> map)
  : id = documentID,
    name = map['customer_name'] as String,
    mobile = map['customer_mobile'] as String,
    type = map['customer_type'] as String;
```

It's set to be non-nullable, because I'm establishing a strict schema. But that shouldn't be a concern, cause it isn't null in the database. I've added `customer_type` to all my documents in the collection. And none of them have the value set to null.

Which could only mean that the map that I get from Firestore, couldn't find the requisite key. Which means I'm still getting the old data (without the new field) from Firestore. What gives? It should give me the updated data when I clear the cache at least.

Comment: Is your collection "customers" exactly named / spelled the same in your FB Console?

Comment: Also there might be a problem with the data snapshot itself, could you please provide the full error message?

Comment: @JahnE. That's the full error. It basically stops the app midway and shows me the debug message. And yes, "customers" is the exact same collection name - correctly spelled. It was working just fine before. It just stopped working when I added the new field.

Answer (score 1):

Because your code is working properly until you add the new field in `Firestore` console, it means that **the problem is with your new field**.

The problem is you either added a field in `Firestore` spelled differently (case sensitive or typo) from your model (class Customer) or the `type` is not appropriate (e.g. you try to read an `int` from a `String`, or you try to read an `array` from a `map`, etc.)

Let me know if this does not help?

Comment: This is absolutely not the case. There is no typo. I've triple checked. And if the type was wrong, it would have told me that e.g. `'int' is not a subtype of 'String' in type cast`. The error explicitly states `null`, which means he can't detect it. And, to top it off, if I reinstall the app, it works just fine.

Comment: @Adifyr You might have spelled everything correct. But nevertheless, the rest you wrote is simply not true. Null is a type, just like int is. Your code detects null (for some reason like your Stream is not listening properly) - To understand cast errors please read this short article from the dart team: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Comment: @JahnE. It is true and I do understand null safety. The String in my model is set to non-nullable. This is intentional design because the new field has been added to all documents in my collection via a script. I'm basically establishing a strict schema. And it is a string on the backend AND in my app. Look at my edited question, when I clear storage, everything works just fine. That wouldn't be the case if I made a casting mistake.

Comment: Understood. Very strange bug. Curious to hear what was the issue when you find it. Good luck ;0)

Answer (score 1):

What I know so far is that the stream returns an immediate local snapshot of the Document before fetching the updated version from the server. Which makes sense; except that if I clear the cache, then it should go to the server directly and not give me any error - which doesn't happen.

I think Firestore might be storing the local snapshot in more places than just the cache, but this is merely speculation on my end.

Currently, I've patched the issue by doing a simple null check in the constructor:

```
type = map['customer_type'] as String? ?? 'customer'
```

This fix is, however, inconclusive and I won't be marking this as the answer as I feel a proper explanation of what's happening is due.

Comment: Have you tested setting persistence to false in your application? According to this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64710447/), erasing the cache might not work properly for this scenario as it rebuilds itself. [Disabling persistence](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#configure-offline-persistence) with the `persistenceEnabled` setting might work for fetching the latest document from Firestore.

Comment: Technically, yes, disabling persistence outright will most probably solve the problem. The thing is, I want to keep persistence enabled in the app. Disabling it seems a lot like trying to kill a fly with a sledgehammer.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar behavior when adding a document field from https://console.firebase.google.com/ (my client was the google/cloud/firestore Ruby gem): Adding a field from the Firebase console in the browser, I was not able to see the new field when querying the same document from my app.

Refreshing the browser page worked for me.  After I did that, adding the field from the Firebase console resulted in the field appearing in my app.